# hash_map: why it defines less, rather than equal_to

Tags: c++, data-structures, stl

C++, using Visual Studio 2010. A question about why a user-defined trait of `hash_map` actually requires total ordering.

I have a simple structure, say `FOO`,  which only has a number of integers. I'd like to use `hash_map`, which is a hash table whose keys are *unordered*, to store the structure of `FOO`. I just need a fast searching of its associated value, so this is a right choice: `hash_map<FOO, int32_t>`.

However, I need to implement my own hash function and some compare functions for `FOO`. Here is the definitions of `hash_map`, taken from MSDN:

```
template <
   class Key, 
   class Type, 
   class Traits=hash_compare<Key, less<Key> >, 
   class Allocator=allocator<pair <const Key, Type> > 
>
class hash_map
```

It turned out that I needed to implement `hash_compare` functors:

```
template<class Key, class Traits = less<Key> >
   class hash_compare
   {
   Traits comp;
public:
   const size_t bucket_size = 4;
   const size_t min_buckets = 8;
   hash_compare( );
   hash_compare( Traits pred );
   size_t operator( )( const Key& _Key ) const; // This is a hash function
   bool operator( )(                            // This is an ordering function
      const Key& _Key1,
      const Key& _Key2
   ) const;
   };
```

Here is the detailed description of the bool operatod() from MSDN:

> For any value _Key1 of type Key that *precedes* _Key2 in the sequence and has the same hash value (value returned by the hash function), hash_comp(_Key2, _Key1) is false. The function must impose a *total ordering* on values of type Key.

The function supplied by hash_compare returns comp(_Key2, _Key1), where comp is a stored object of type Traits that you can specify when you construct the object hash_comp. For the default Traits parameter type less, sort keys never decrease in value.

It was easy to write the `hash_compare` class for `FOO`. This question is *not* for asking how to implement a class. However, it's not straightforward for me that why they have the default trait parameter as `less<key>` and require total ordering.

`hash_map` is an *unordered* data structure. So, I thought that it would be sufficient to have `equal_to` or `not_equal_to` instead of `less` or `greater`. However, the description of MSDN explicitly states that keys are ordered, which confuses me.

Did I misunderstand the definition of `hash_map`? Why STL's `hash_map` actually require orders of its key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For any value _Key1 of type Key that *precedes* _Key2 in the sequence and has the same hash value (value
>   returned by the hash function), hash_comp(_Key2, _Key1) is false. The function must impose a
>   *total ordering* on values of type Key.

A total ordering of keys with the same hash value guarantees a total ordering of keys which hash to the same bucket.

That provides the opportunity for a more efficient implementation of search for a key *within a particular bucket* - e.g. Θ(log n) binary search is possible.  If there is no such guaranteed ordering, the worst case (many different keys which are all in the same bucket because they all hash to the same value) is Θ(n).

Comment: I don't think such total ordering is helpful for search. this because 1) the hash function should be uniform, and with load_factor < 1, it means, in most case, one element per hash slot. i.e. no need binary search. 2) obviously, it will slow down insertion.

Comment: @Chang, unless you know all the possible keys ahead of time there's no way to guarantee one element per slot - in fact one kind of DOS attack uses knowledge of the hash function to produce collisions on purpose. And no, it's *not* obvious that it will slow down insertion.

Answer (score 3):

`hash_map` that you are looking at  is a Microsoft extension that came in in VS2003 and is actually now in `stdext` in Visual C++ - it's not part of the STL.

`std::unordered_map` is the **official** STL version of an associative container with value access by hashable key - the predicate on that is for equality, as you expected.

```
template<class Key,
    class Ty,
    class Hash = std::hash<Key>,
    class Pred = std::equal_to<Key>,
    class Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const Key, Ty> > >
    class unordered_map;
```

Answer (score 2):

The exact requirements on `hash_map` vary with the implementation, and some of them (as you've seen) don't make a whole lot of sense. That's part of why they decided **not** to include a `hash_map` (or `hash_*`) in TR1 and/or C++0x. Instead, they have `unordered_[multi](map|set)`, which requires only `equal_key`, not `operator<`.

Bottom line: unless you have a truly outstanding reason to do otherwise, use `unordered_map` instead of `hash_map`.

Comment: +1 for an interesting history lesson, but I don't think it quite answers the question...

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I should use unordered_map. I'm wondering what unique features exist for hash_map over map and unordered_map.

Comment: @minjang: map is ordered (normally implemented as a balanced tree) so it supports things like finding items in a range. unordered_map gives O(1) insertion/deletion/lookup. hash_map is similar to unordered_map, but there's no spec to follow, so different versions have different features, requirements, etc.